# Convert nested html-table to nested-dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am writting an application convert the html-table string data receive from website (by calling RESR API) to dictionary format. The problem is that the format of HTML table string is nested HTML table format. After a while doing search on the internet i cannot find the solution for this case. Eventhough It have a lot of solution to convert the json to html. My HTML table string input is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>sku</th>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>capacity</th>
                                <td>1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>name</th>
                                <td>Developer</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>tags</th>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>properties</th>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>gatewayRegionalUrl</th>
                                <td>https:test</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>createdAtUtc</th>
                                <td>2019-03-18T08:11:21.0001331Z</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>virtualNetworkType</th>
                                <td>None</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>additionalLocations</th>
                                <td>None</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>customProperties</th>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Protocols.Server.Http2</th>
                                            <td>False</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>certificates</th>
                                <td>None</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>etag</th>
                    <td>AAAAAAFy3Vo=</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>type</th>
                    <td>test/service</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <td>/test</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use python library BeautifulSoup for processing HTML string with method find_all() to find all the table tag and extract th and td tag for key and value but the problem is how can I process the the sub table tag inside another table tag. I had thinking about of using recrusive function with BeautifulSoup library to solve this, Does anyone suggest me how to do it ?

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

str_html = "<table><tr><td><table><tr><th>sku</th><td><table><tr><th>capacity</th><td>1</td></tr><tr><th>name</th><td>Developer</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><th>tags</th><td></td></tr><tr><th>properties</th><td><table><tr><th>gatewayRegionalUrl</th><td>https:test/td></tr><tr><th>createdAtUtc</th><td>2019-03-18T08:11:21.0001331Z</td></tr><tr><th>virtualNetworkType</th><td>None</td></tr><tr><th>additionalLocations</th><td>None</td></tr><tr><th>customProperties</th><td><table><tr><th>Protocols.Server.Http2</th><td>False</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><th>certificates</th><td>None</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><th>etag</th><td>AAAAAAFy3Vo=</td></tr><tr><th>type</th><td>test/service</td></tr><tr><th>id</th><td>test</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>"
print(type(str_html))
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    keys = [th.get_text(strip=True)for th in table.find_all('th')]
    values = [td.get_text("strip=True) for td in table.find_all('td')]
    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    print(d)
```

> My expectation result output is:

```
             {
                "etag": "AAAAAAFy3Vo=",
                "id": "test",
                "properties": {
                    "additionalLocations": null,
                    "certificates": null,
                    "createdAtUtc": "2019-03-18T08:11:21.0001331Z",
                    "customProperties": {
                        "Protocols.Server.Http2": "False",
                    },
                    "gatewayRegionalUrl": "https:test",
                    "virtualNetworkType": "None"
                },
                "sku": {
                    "capacity": 1,
                    "name": "Developer"
                },
                "tags": {},
                "type": "test/service"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lxml library to parse the html document like this:

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(page_html)
```

After that, you could extract the **th** blocks like this:

```
ths = doc.xpath('//th'):
```

And iterate in each **th** block to extract the pair (key,value) in the same way.
Finally, convert the data to json.